makepkg error due to unknown option "!lto"
I am trying to build a package from the AUR with makepkg. I ran "makepkg PKGBUILD" and receive dthe following error: "options array contains unknown option '!lto'" I have checked my config file /etc/makepkg.conf but this option ("!lto") is not present in the options array. Could it be the makepkg is reading options from another config file? I have already checked "/etc/makepkg.conf.d/makepkg.conf", "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pacman/makepkg.conf", and "~/.makepkg.conf". I am running this command as a non-root user in a non-root directory. My distro is Hyperbola GNU/Linux-libre.
